# Ruby on rails: What's the difference between respond_to and respond_with?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What's the difference between `respond_to` and `respond_with` ?
What do they do?
Can anyone post example with the screenshot of output?

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't it `respond_to` instead of `respond_do`? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 13):

There is a pretty complete answer [here](http://davidwparker.com/2010/03/09/api-in-rails-respond-to-and-respond-with/).  Essentially respond_with does the same thing as respond_to but makes your code a bit cleaner.  It is only available in rails 3 I think

Comment: This is basically it, respond_with just cleans everything up and automates a lot of it. This link goes into a bit more detail: http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/8/6/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-cleaner-restful-controllers-w-respond_with

Answer (score 2):

Both **respond_to** and **respond_with** does the same work, but **respond_with** tends to make code a bit simple,

Here in this example,

```
def create
  @task = Task.new(task_params)

  respond_to do |format|
   if @task.save
    format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @task }
   else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
 end
end
```

The same code using **respond_with** ,

```
def create
  @task = Task.new(task_params)
  flash[:notice] = "Task was successfully created." if @task.save
  respond_with(@task)
end
```

also you need to mention the formats in your controller as:

```
respond_to :html,:json,:xml
```

When we pass `@task`to respond_with, it will actually check if the object is valid? first. If the object is not valid, then it will call render :new when in a create or render :edit when in an update.

If the object is valid, it will automatically redirect to the show action for that object.

Maybe you would rather redirect to the index after successful creation. You can override the redirect by adding the `:location` option to respond_with:

```
def create
  @task = Task.new(task_params)
  flash[:notice] = @task.save ? "Your task was created." : "Task failed to save." 
  respond_with @task, location: task_path
end
```

For more information visit this [Blog](https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/respond-to-without-all-the-pain//)